# List of questions reverting back when using the back button

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

If I view a question and then press the back button in my browser, the list of questions tends to revert back to an older version than the one I was viewing when going to the question. Often, this is remedied by refreshing, but not always.

I am using Chromium and I view the list of active questions.

Comment: I'm seeing something possibly related when I have changed the sorting order of a list, such as changing the list of my answers from "newest" to "votes". After I backspace back to the list, it will show the answers in "newest" order, but the "votes" button will be nonfunctional, as if the button logic though the list was currently sorted by votes. The behavior when paging through a some (but not all) multipage lists is similar.

Answer (score 1):

This definitely sounds like a browser issue, as if the browser is using a stale cache, or not recording the AJAX updates (in response to clicking the "xx questions with new activity" button).

The only thing that might be the site's fault would be if the site is not changing the Last-modified date when AJAX updates the Questions page (in response to clicking the "xx questions with new activity" button). However, if you were looking at a later page, your browser should not take you back to an earlier page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the realtime updates when on the homepage then yes, this is by design at the moment.  We do have some ideas for how to make this experience better, so stay tuned and thanks for the report.